# Is there a place to ask about the impact on creativity in programming when taking an education?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't think what I'm asking for is fit for Stack Exchange, but I felt I should at least ask anyway.

I'm a self taught programmer who's been working in the field for a couple of years. I took a look at some tests from courses in a good school nearby, and felt like it was all about right/wrong rather than creativity and making things awesome.

Now I'm looking for advice from someone who can share some experience on how schooling has impacted their personal style and joy of programming. Is there a place to ask such a question on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SE site for this kind of thing, because it is literally a question about sharing personal experience.
However, once you have 20 or more points on an SE site, you will be allowed to participate in that site's chat - where personal experience is allowed, depending on the chatroom.
For this particular subject, you'd have to find a chatroom on Stack Overflow or Programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the specific topic for a second and consider this:

1. You are basically looking to get into a discussion about `x`
2. Poll users for their opinions on that discussion and that topic.

That is not really a Q&A type question so wouldn't be on-topic on any SE site.

However, [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) may be an option as the format is more suitable for discussing and opinions